# DateTime locale string not change even I changed the locale in app in android

Tags: android, date, datetime, locale, setlocale

In my android app, I have successfully implemented the language change part.

The problem is, the DateTime locale is based on the device locale but not the in app locale, for example, when I switch in app locale from English to Germany, while the device locale is English

The string / draw-able etc are obtained from my Germany string folder, but the date remains in the English one e.g. JAN , FEB , etc...

And here is my code to get the month

```
DateFormatSymbols.getInstance().getShortMonths()[position]
```

Also , the way to display date

```
String relativeString = getRelativeDateTimeString (this, System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS,DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS, 0));
```

How to fix that? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how to get date in locale this solution is

```
 DateFormat formatter;
 formatter = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT, new Locale("de", "DE"));
 String result = formatter.format(new Date());
```

from this you get get idea and get help and if you stuck than fill free to ask me :)

i have refer

1. [DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html)
2. [DateFormat example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/DateFormatwithLocale.htm)