# how to avoid locale timezone conversion when working with JS Date function

Tags: javascript, time, timezone

How to avoid the local timezone conversions when working with new Date() in javascript, for example, today is "2022-03-24", if I use new Date("2022-03-24") I'll be getting different dates in different countries, how to avoid this conversation and use only the date, also I need the date object because of the date picker.

is this a solution?

```
let date = new Date(2022, 02, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: [this might be able to answer your question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25417978/datetime-locale-string-not-change-even-i-changed-the-locale-in-app-in-android)
I'm unable to comment, so I've used an answer to help.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- Your example of `new Date("2022-03-24")` will have the input will be interpreted as midnight UTC due to the format you used.  It's identical to `new Date("2022-03-24T00:00:00.000Z")`.  You'd also get the same result with `new Date(Date.UTC(2022, 2, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0))`.
- Your example of `new Date(2022, 2, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0)` will have the input interpreted as *local time* due to the constructor you used.  It gives the same output as `new Date("2022-03-24T00:00:00.000")` (without the `Z`).
- The `Date` object itself has no time zone - it is just a wrapper around a UTC-based Unix timestamp.
- What you *do* with the resulting `Date` object has as much to do with whether you will observe a time zone conversion as creating it does.  For example, `toString` will provide a string representation in terms of local time, but `toISOString` will provide a string representation in terms of UTC.
- Thus, the only way to *completely* avoid any time zone conversions is to construct in terms of UTC and then only use functions that output in terms of UTC (like `toISOString`) or get/set in terms of UTC (like `getUTCHours`, `setUTCHours`, etc.)
- You mentioned you are using a date picker.

  - Many date pickers will have properties that give you back a `Date` object, but *some* will instead give you back a string in yyyy-mm-dd format.  If your goal is to pass along the chosen date to a back end API, you should *avoid* using a `Date` object.  Just take the string and send that instead.  The standard `<input type="date">` is a good example.  See [the docs for its `Value` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#value) for more details.
  - If your date picker *only* provides a `Date` object, then chances are it was constructed in terms of the user's local time zone.  You should make a date string in yyyy-mm-dd format yourself (using the local time based properties `getFullYear`, `getMonth`, and `getDate`), and then pass that to your API.